# Android, Java only gets last word from string array

Tags: java, android, arrays, contains

I have build a java app which use voice recognition, I created a string array like this:

```
String[] greetings = {"hello", "hi", "yow"};
```

Now the problem is is that the app is only detecting the last word of the array "yow", not "hello" or "hi"

```
for (String strings: greetings) 

                 { if (mostLikelyThingHeard.contains(strings)) {
                            tts.speak("Hey nice to see you!",
                                    TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
```

So I really don't know what I am doing wrong, maybe `mostLikelyThingHeard` needs a 'for' loop also?

Full code:

```
package nl.giovanniterlingen.pws;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.speech.RecognizerIntent;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.OnInitListener;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Main extends Activity implements OnInitListener {
    private static final String TAG = "PWS";

    private TextView result;

    private TextToSpeech tts;

    private Button speak;

    private int SPEECH_REQUEST_CODE = 1234;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        speak = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_speak);
        speak.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                sendRecognizeIntent();
            }
        });

        speak.setEnabled(false);
        result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_result);

        tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onInit(int status) {
        if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
            speak.setEnabled(true);
        } else {
            // failed to init
            finish();
        }

    }

    private void sendRecognizeIntent() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
                RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Aan het luisteren...");
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS, 100);
        startActivityForResult(intent, SPEECH_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == SPEECH_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                ArrayList<String> matches = data
                        .getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);

                if (matches.size() == 0) {
                    tts.speak("Ik heb niks gehoord, probeer het nog eens",
                            TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
                } else {
                    String mostLikelyThingHeard = matches.get(0);
                    result.setText("Dit heeft u gezegd: "
                            + mostLikelyThingHeard + ".");
                    String doei = "doei";
                    String[] greetings = { "hello", "hi", "yow" };

                    for (String strings : greetings) {

                        if (mostLikelyThingHeard.contains(strings)) {
                            tts.speak("Hey nice to see you!",
                                    TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);

                        } else if (mostLikelyThingHeard.equals(doei)) {
                            tts.speak("Okay tot de volgende keer!",
                                    TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
                        } else {
                            tts.speak("Ik begrijp niet wat je bedoeld met "
                                    + mostLikelyThingHeard
                                    + " probeer het anders te verwoorden.",
                                    TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "result NOT ok");
            }
        }

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        if (tts != null) {
            tts.shutdown();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to speak "hello", "hi", "yow" at the same time? Because in that case, the loop will get executed thrice and due to TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, previous utterances will be flushed out.

Comment: `String[] greetings = { "hallo", "hi", "yow" };` where is the "hello"?

Comment: well, you are not breaking out of your loop after recognizing a word. if you say "hi" and your programm also recognize "hi" it will still check for other words.

Comment: print what you got mostLikelyThingHeard ? to see where exactly the error are

Comment: Do you know how to set breakpoints in your code and run the app in debug mode?

Comment: Nope one word at one time, so for example if I say: "yow I'm Giovanni!" It detects the word "yow"so it wil speak: Hey nice to see you! But if I say "hello" or "hi" it doesn't then it says: "Ik begrijp niet wat je bedoeld met" (See 'else')

Comment: No I don't know how to use breakpoints, and yeah I'm sorry about the 'hallo' I translated it here for you guys ;)

Comment: Sir you write hallo and it should be hello so print what you got to make sure compare work fine or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the only problem I am seeing is that you're checking for "doei" inside the for... Besides that, it should work ok. also, consider ensuring the thing heard is in the case you're expecting it to be.
Also, you should keep track of the fact that you found a word or not in the for.

```
String doei = "doei";
String[] greetings = { "hallo", "hi", "yow" };
mostLikelyThingHeard = mostLikelyThingHeard.toLowerCase();
boolean found = false;

for (String strings : greetings) {
    if (mostLikelyThingHeard.contains(strings)) {
        tts.speak("Hey nice to see you!",
            TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
        found = true;
        break;
    }
} 
if (!found) { 
    if (mostLikelyThingHeard.equals(doei)) {
        tts.speak("Okay tot de volgende keer!", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
    } else {
        tts.speak("Ik begrijp niet wat je bedoeld met "
          + mostLikelyThingHeard
          + " probeer het anders te verwoorden.",
          TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Will try now, thanks! / Still not detecting first two words... Only "yow"

Comment: By the way, now it isn't even detecting any of the array's words :(

Comment: well, its all about the content of mostLikelyThingHeard, and we dont know what you get there.

Comment: YOU DID IT MAN :D ROSES ARE RED VIOLETS ARE BLUE @user1961779 you made my day so all thanks goes to you xD

Comment: @user1961779 how can I delete the .equals(doei)) without corrupting the above script?

Comment: if (!found && !mostLikelyThingHeard.equals(doei)) { tts.speak("Ik begrijp niet wat je bedoeld met "
          + mostLikelyThingHeard
          + " probeer het anders te verwoorden.",
          TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null); }

Answer (score 1):

You can take all words in a single string (not array string).I know that's would not be the best solution so I am providing you a simple example in which whatever you write the engine will speak.

```
MainActivity.java
package com.authorwjf.talk2me;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.speech.RecognizerIntent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    protected static final int REQUEST_OK = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        findViewById(R.id.button1).setOnClickListener(this);
    }


}
//The on click handler is responsible for firing off the voice intent. 

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
Intent i = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
         i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, "en-US");
             try {
             startActivityForResult(i, REQUEST_OK);
         } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Error initializing speech to text engine.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         }
}

//When the intent calls back, we display the transcribed text.

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode==REQUEST_OK  && resultCode==RESULT_OK) {
                ArrayList<String> thingsYouSaid = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
                ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.text1)).setText(thingsYouSaid.get(0));
        }
    }

//activity_main.xml

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="132dp"
        android:text="..." ></TextView>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="37dp"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_btn_speak_now" ></ImageButton>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: If I put everything in one String then the user has to say that full string which isn't useful :(

Comment: Its okay .In above code the text will be saved in textview when user speak something .finally use the textview text to speak .